# assigning columns of data frames with get function R

Tags: r

I have a data frame(s) df1,df2,... that I am accessing through a for loop (R for loop I know...) I need to assign the last column (y variable) to be a factor. I am attempting to do it like this:

```
get(paste0('df',x))[,ncol(get(paste0('df',x)))] <- as.factor(get(paste0('df',x))[,ncol(get(paste0('df',x)))])
```

however I am getting the 'target of assignment expands to non-language object' error when I try to do this.

Why is this not behaving the same way as this?

```
df1[,19] <- as.factor(df1[,19])
```

and is there a way to assign my columns as factors given that it must be done through a process similar to this?

Comment: You cannot assign via `get()`. Code generally avoid `get()` and `set()` which don't work with data.frame extraction. When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. There is probably a more R-like way to do what you are trying to do that doesn't involved `get()`.

Comment: I'm 99% sure that if you show us more about your case we can end up with something much more elegant

Comment: @MrFlick, do you mean `assign()`? (I agree, both functions should generally be avoided and will not work well here.)

Comment: @r2evans Yep. I meant assign(). My bad.

Comment: Seeing unnecessary use of `get()` in R is remniscent of excel's `INDIRECT` function, and should be avoided about as urgently.